# Representations of some primes as $x^2-2y^2$?

Tags: prime-numbers, diophantine-equations, quadratic-forms, quadratic-residues, diophantine-approximation

I am looking for (elementary) proofs (idea of the proofs is also OK) or references to proofs of the followings:

$$
p\equiv\pm1(\mod8)\longrightarrow p=x^2-2y^2
$$

Any help appreciated.

Comment: When you asked this question on MO, it was suggested that you look at some intro Number Theory textbooks. Did you?

Answer (score 1):

This is the general idea.

**Pigeonhole Principle**

Note, that since $k$ is a quadratic residue, this implies there exists such $a$ that $a^2 \equiv k \pmod p$.

By [Thue's Lemma](https://karushib.wordpress.com/2015/09/27/a-nice-lemma-in-congruence), we get that there exists such $-\sqrt{p}< x,y < \sqrt{p}$ that $x \equiv ay \pmod {p}$.

**EXAMPLE**

Assume that $p \equiv \pm 1 \pmod 8.

Note, that since $2$ is a quadratic residue, this implies there exists such $a$ that $a^2 \equiv 2 \pmod p$.

By [Thue's Lemma](https://karushib.wordpress.com/2015/09/27/a-nice-lemma-in-congruence), we get that there exists such $-\sqrt{p}< x,y < \sqrt{p}$ that $x \equiv ay \pmod {p}$.

This implies that $x^2-a^2y^2 \equiv x^2-2y^2 \equiv 0 \pmod {p}$.

Note that $-2p<x^2-2y^2<p$.

This implies that that $p=2y^2-x^2$ which is equivalent to saying $p=(2y+x)^2-2(x+y)^2$.